# Yup: How to access the "inner" propriety in ValidationError() method

Tags: javascript, yup, validationerror

Yup contain a method name validationError whose one of properties is "inner". Accordingly with the documentation:

> in the case of aggregate errors, inner is an array of ValidationErrors
> throw earlier in the validation chain. When the abortEarly option is
> false this is where you can inspect each error thrown, alternatively,
> errors will have all of the messages from each inner error.

However, it's properly working is not quite clear to me. How exactly I do to access this property and use it in my code.

Here, I'm trying to use in this application but it seems not working.

```
function validator (req, res, next) {

yup.setLocale({
    mixed: {
        default: 'Não é válido',
      }
});

 const schema = yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required("Legendary name is required"),
    type: yup.string().required("Legendary type is required"),
    description: yup.string().required("Legendary description is required").min(10)
});

 let messageError = new yup.ValidationError([`${req.body.name}`, `${req.body.type}`, `${req.body.description}`]);

 if(!schema.isValidSync(req.body, {abortEarly: false})) {
    return res.status(400).json(messageError.inner);
 }
```

When I run it with insomnia, I get a empty array only.

Can someone help me with this, please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ValidationError`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#validationerrorerrors-string--arraystring-value-any-path-string) is thrown is by the `validate*` methods (`validate`, `validateSync`, `validateAt`, and `validateSyncAt`) when the validation fails. [`isValidSync`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedisvalidsyncvalue-any-options-object-boolean) returns a boolean and doesn't throw any errors. Use [`validateSync`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedvalidatesyncvalue-any-options-object-any) and add a `catch` block to access the validation errors.

`messageError.inner` returns an empty array since `messageError` is a standalone `ValidationError` object which isn't associated with the schema in any way.

```
try {
  schema.validateSync(req.body, { abortEarly: false })
} catch (err) {
  // err is of type ValidationError
  return res.status(400).json(err.inner)
}
```

```sh
curl -s -X POST http://localhost:5000/test | jq        
[
  {
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "path": "name",
    "type": "required",
    "errors": [
      "Legendary name is required"
    ],
    "inner": [],
    "message": "Legendary name is required",
    "params": {
      "path": "name"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "path": "type",
    "type": "required",
    "errors": [
      "Legendary type is required"
    ],
    "inner": [],
    "message": "Legendary type is required",
    "params": {
      "path": "type"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "path": "description",
    "type": "required",
    "errors": [
      "Legendary description is required"
    ],
    "inner": [],
    "message": "Legendary description is required",
    "params": {
      "path": "description"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You came as light at the end of tunel Arun ! thank you very much  !! 

But I still can't understand very well what has happend here. An "inner" property returns to every uncomplish requisition in schema a validationError, which is an object whose one of its properties is the "inner" itself ? So the ValidationError() method contains a property that returns the properties of the method ?...

cuco, I bugged here !

Comment: @FabianoVasconcelosSant'Anna Haha, I'm glad to help. The `inner` property returns an array of errors which are `ValidationError`s. That's why you find the `path`, `errors`, and `inner` property in each element of the `inner` array.